# Execute query foreach value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, stored-procedures

I have a table of `Users`.

 

 
The columns are:

 
 - `UserID` (`Int`)
 - `IsConnected` (`Bit` - true/false).

I want to create a stored procedure that will set all the users to disconnected.

To optimize the query I thought first to get the ids of all the connected users, and then foreach id of connected user, run query to set `isConnected = 0`.

My question is, how can I run the "disconnect" query, based on a list of ids which comes from an other query/table?

Waiting for help,

Thanks!!

Comment: UPDATE Users SET IsConnected=false

Comment: yeah but this way you waste resources, updating 1,000,000 users instead only 5 users (which really need to be disconnected).

Comment: UPDATE Users SET IsConnected=false WHERE IsConnected=true

Comment: `UPDATE Users SET IsConnected = 0 WHERE UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM SomeOtherTable)`

Comment: Thanks guys! 
which query will be faster ? 
UPDATE Users SET IsConnected=false WHERE IsConnected=true
or
 UPDATE Users SET IsConnected = 0 WHERE UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM SomeOtherTable)

?

Comment: Possibly the WHERE one. A column containing only true/false is not sargable, therefore no index can be used on it, therefore it first needs to search through 1000000 records to find the IsConnected=true records anyway. Then it just writes the five records back. If 10000000 reads + 5 writes is faster than 1000000 writes then the WHERE one will be quicker. But the only way to know is to check the query plan and test.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid *"A column containing only true/false is not sargable, therefore no index can be used on it"* - Yes it can. Given an even distribution of data it is often not worth creating an index, but it definitely can be indexed, and the index can be used in queries.

Comment: @user3125999 - It is not a question of which query will be faster - it is a question of which query is suitable. If you just need to set disconnected to false where disconnected is currently true, then `UPDATE Users SET IsConnected=false WHERE IsConnected=true` will work fine. If, as your question states, you need to use the results of another query, then this won't be suitable. I think you need to update the question to include table structures, sample data, and a more specific set of rules in order to get a complete answer

Comment: @GarethD - true, I stand corrected... if the stats indicate the index is effective it'll be used.